# why ontouchstart not support DOM 0 level events

Tags: javascript, events, dom

When I use the DOM 0 level events bind touchstart on document is not work,the code like that:

```
document.ontouchstart = function(){alert("a")}
```

But DOM 2 event into force,the code like that:

```
document.addEventListener( "touchstart" , function(){
    alert("a");
} , false);
```

I would like to know why this is and there have some ways make the DOM 0 level events working??

Comment: Attaching an event handler by the `ontouchstart` property works fine for me. What device are you testing this on? [Try this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdgluck/esd8ndz3/) (and look at the console).

Comment: Of course, there are *other* reasons for not using DOM0-style events...

Comment: I use the Chrome DevTool mobile simulator, but is not work